# Using Windows Native L&F on a Mac (Java/Swing)

Tags: java, macos, swing, look-and-feel

Is there a way that I could use the Windows Native L&F while making a GUI with Swing?

I am using a Mac and I don't want to use a cross platform L&F (like Nimbus or Metal). Also, I know that I can create my own L&F, but I was wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: I remember that when I last developed a Swing application years ago, I once saw the possibility to have a windows l&f, but unfortunately, I don't remember how.

Comment: *"Is there a way that I could use the Windows Native L&F (on a Mac) while making a GUI with Swing?"* Not legally, but just don't even try it anyway. Mac users will not thank you for trying to shove a Windows looking GUI into their OS X experience. (Just like I'll not like to see the Aqua look Quick Time player imported onto my PC.)